# Using ruby scan split join with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

```
@string = "Hello.My email is james@email.com and my name is James."
```

I want to add a space specifically between periods and capital letters. I want to change `@string` to:

```
"Hello. My email is james@email.com and my name is James."
```

I have the following code:

```
@string.scan(/.[A-Z]/)
# => [".M"]
```

Comment: Timmy, please precise what the output should be for a `M.B.S` string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am looking to adjust for sentences that were not properly spaced, so M.B.S would not require any spaces between periods.

Comment: Timmy, Wiktor's point is that you have not defined sentences that are  "improperly spaced". Consider "I have a friend named J.A.A  Lovink" (an actual person, incidentally). What rule says this is a properly-spaced sentence?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Right. So what I came up with myself was `input.gsub!(/([^A-Z])(\.)([A-Z])/, '\1 \2')` however that does not properly deal with `B.S.` which also should not contain spaces.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a `.` you need to use an escaped dot. You also need to use `gsub`, not `scan` as you need to perform a replace operation.

Use

```
s = "Hello.My email is james@email.com and my name is James."
s = s.gsub(/\.\K(?=[[:upper:]])/, ' ')
```

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/h0er2q). A capturing group variation that still allows consecutive matches:

```
s = s.gsub(/(\.)(?=[[:upper:]])/, '\1 ')
```

Or lookbehind one:

```
s = s.gsub(/(?<=\.)(?=[[:upper:]])/, ' ')
```

**Details**

- `\.` - a literal dot
- `\K` - a match reset operator (`(?<=\.)` is equal to `\.\K` in functionality)
- `(?=[[:upper:]])` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of an uppercase letter immediately to the right of the current location.

In the capturing group based pattern, `(\.)` forms Group 1 and `\1` inserts the value back when replacing.

Here is a way to deal with `U.S.` like words:

```
s = "Hello.My email is james@email.com and my name is M.B.S James."
rx = /(\b[[:upper:]](?:\.[[:upper:]])+)\b|\.([[:upper:]])/
puts s.gsub(rx) { |m| 
  m == $~[1] ? $~[1] : ". #{$~[2]}" 
}
```

See [another Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/nczPDS)

Here,

- `\b([[:upper:]](?:\.[[:upper:]])+)\b` - a single uppercase letter followed with 1 or more `.` + 1 or more uppercase letters, captured into Group 1.
- `|` - or
- `\.([[:upper:]])` - a dot and the uppercase letter captured into Group 2.

If Group 1 matches, `$~[1]` (Group 1 value) is inserted back, else `.`  is used for replacement. Note that `$~` is the match data object currently in use inside `gsub`, and `$~[N]` is Group N value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `gsub`

```
@string = "Hello.My email is james@email.com and my name is James."
@string.gsub!(/(\.)([A-Z])/, '\1 \2')
```

Output:

```
"Hello. My email is james@email.com and my name is James."
```

**Update:**

Another good way to do it would be by using a positive lookahead, thanks for @CarySwoveland for suggesting that

```
@string = "Hello.My email is james@email.com and my name is James."
@string.gsub(/\.(?=[A-Z])/, '. ')
```

Comment: I did not post this solution on purpose because it does not handle strings like `M.B.S` - actually, OP has no mentioning what should be done in these cases and I assumed spaces must be inserted between each dot and uppercase letter.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think using groups is usually more flexible and has unlimited possibilities, and it can be tweaked to account for this case. My regex is based entirely on the OP own regex which is `/.[A-Z]/`

Comment: No one is forbidding to use groups, see my second suggestion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I like it. I'm still not sure though what the OP would want for cases like `M.B.S` . I'll leave it to him to decide.

Comment: You might find it easier to use a positive lookahead rather than capture groups: `@string.gsub(/\.(?=[A-Z])/, '. ')`

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you for your suggestion, a positive lookahead is indeed another good way to do it. I updated my answer. thanks